# how to generate a non-pseudo random number in .net on windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, random-seed

How can I generate a non-pseudo (ie. truly) random number in .Net Framework (latest) running on an Azure Windows 10 Pro virtual machine?

Obviously, it must periodically self-seed by a function of some external variant, such as some counter within the operating system, like Internet event counts, or some count of user action/input, or other.

Comment: Why do you need to seed it if it is a non-prng? If you have a true random number generator, go, and use it.

Comment: There is `System.Random()` you can give a seed here to "reset" it.
There is `RNGCryptoServiceProvider()` to generate more secure random bytes and numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by *non-pseudo random number*?  Do you mean *A deterministic number*?  Or *A truly random number generated from external noise*?  Or *A technically psuedo-random number but one of higher quality than `System.Random`?*  Did you see [How can I generate truly (not pseudo) random numbers with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1234094/3744182)?  If that doesn't answer your question, is there some specific difficulty when running on an Azure VM, e.g. with getting random seeds?

Comment: DanielTuzes:  I meant non-pseudo must self-seed. dbc: yes, truly random.

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I generate truly (not pseudo) random numbers with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234094/how-can-i-generate-truly-not-pseudo-random-numbers-with-c)

Comment: If your npRNG self-seeds after a while is it still really random inbetween??

Answer (score 0):

RNGCryptoServiceProvider() is self-seeding apparently from external variants.  I will use it.  I hope it's fast.